# Design Question

Tags: workflow, design

I am having trouble deciding what the best way to proceed here is.  The project I am working on involves multiple asset types with multiple 'trips' that can require multiple assets of varying types.  I need to be able to display a schedule of the trips, as well as a small schedule for each user (the scheduling will be plenty difficult, but that's for later).  The problem I am looking at is deciding whether it would be better to submit trip itineraries through a form library or a list form.  Either way, a workflow seems necessary to propagate data to other lists (right now, I am hoping to be able to accomplish my task using various Asset lists- one for each type- a Trip list, and a Roster list that simply correlates Trip IDs with Asset IDs).

I'm trying to decide which would be the best option- form library or list form.  Any suggestions?  Is this project even possible?  (Bear in mind that I cannot get access to the server beyond the basic ways, i.e. SPD and InfoPath, as the IT department refuses to return my emails, so it is unlikely that I will be able to add any significant code)

**EDIT:**  I should add that the option I am currently looking at involves using a form library to store Trips, with lists for the various assets and a list that stores the correlation between assets and trips.  The workflow would make sure that the data matched between these lists and libraries, and the correlation list would be hidden from user access.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you present here your project is possible with the tools you have (the caveat being you have only provided an overview of your requirements and not a full requirements document). The Form Library may be an advantage so that items are stored as forms in the way they were filled out. You can format the forms in InfoPath to fit the way you would like a trip itinerary to display, so you can make more complex forms in this manner that sounds like what your requirements mandate. You can create different forms for different content types which represent your asset/trip types, and create workflows on these as well using SP Designer. Of course the same thing can essentially be accomplished with a normal list, and you can even format that list form in InfoPath, but you will only be saving list items, so really it depends on how you want to see the data after submittal.

Comment: One of the nice things about this project is that the requirements I mention are approximately the requirements I was given- as long as it turns out to be usable and better than the current solution (a massive shared Excel sheet), I have a bit of leeway as to how it actually works.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call it "nice" to have requirements as vague as that :) But hey, to each his own.

Comment: I can appreciate that, but it's nice to have some creative freedom every now and again.  Plus, with as much difficulty as I'm having with this project, it's definitely helpful to be able to bend the requirements to fit what I can actually get to work.